# Remove that ugly skype banner

Tags: skype

How can I remove that ugly banner in Skype? It showed up in the latest version but I think it is pretty annoying.

I know I can go back to the latest version but I would rather keep my software up to date (you know, viruses and malware and stuff) so I'm looking for something that can fix this problem in the current version of skype (and possibly newer ones)

Comment: You can become a premium member and you won't see any ads.

Answer (score 7):

Put

```
127.0.0.1 rad.msn.com
127.0.0.1 apps.skype.com
```

in your HOSTS file. Done.

Answer (score 6):

Luckily, there is a way:

1. Start Internet Explorer and click on the cog icon (or press ALT+X)
2. Go to Internet Options > Security
3. Click Restricted Sites and click on the Sites button
4. Enter https://apps.skype.com/ in the textbox and click Add.
5. Click Close and OK

(see [here](http://www.jaoord.nl/remove-annoying-ad-skype))

Comment: It doesnt remove the banner panel. Look Umamaheswaran answer.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try this

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-ads-in-skype/

It not only removes the ad but it removes the whole bar.

Overview of the steps listed in the link

1. Add  https://apps.skype.com in restricted sites
2. Open config file of skype. You can find the config.xml in directory similar to the below example
   C:\users[your user name]\App Data\Roaming\Skype[your Skype username]
3. Search for AdvertPlaceholder tag and remove the line
4. Then make the config.xml readonly to restrict skype from adding it automatically again.

Thanks

Comment: Best solution! Remove whole bar is what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Linux Skype client and there is no ads at all on it, so I am not sure my advice would help you.

You can use a network sniffer (like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) to see the IP the software is trying to load ads from. If it is always the same (it should first retrieve the list of ads, I guess), you can try to block it in your hosts file (by assigning 127.0.0.1 as a alias of this IP, so every request to get ads are redirected to your PC and then fail).

But if Skype is retrieving the ads from the same server as it uses to connect yourself to the Skype services (for communicating with your contacts) it may just break everything...

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tool that automatically removes the entire Skype advertising. http://www.mediafire.com/download/3s1903x5vc0cfvn/Skype_Werbung_weg.exe
Therefore you have to enter your username, because the settings are at %AppData%\Skype and then in a folder with the Skype name. But it will not be given to me or third,this shows the fact, that it easily works without Internet.
The Tool is Written in German, because I´am from Germany. If you can read in it "Bitte Skype Kontonamen (der nicht aenderbare) eingeben.
(Klicke in Skype auf deinen Namen [Oben links]
und dann siehst du ihn oben recht unter "Konten"):" It means, that you have to enter your Skype Account name. You can find it, in Skype with an click to your username (at the top right corner) and than you can see it under "Accounts" (At the top right) Tipp: if you have linked with Microsoft, it´s not your Microsoft email Address.
If you are interested: This tool is a packed batch with an extra tool to easily add things to hosts file. You can simply unpack with WinRar or 7Zip for example and in the batch I still have some notes for operation made.

Is recognized scanners at VirusTotal of about 3 of 50 viruses, because it´s changing the hosts file...
The Notes in the Batch script are also in German.
Hopefully you could understand my bad English.